# what are the odds of hitting a flush with 2 suited cards before the floop

Tags: flush, drawing

what are the odds to hit a flush if you hold two suited cards pre flop. 
In a tournament 3 guys go all in I was in last position. I had suited 10/J and called as I was getting 4-1 on my money.
 was that a good call?

Answer (score 2):

as a rule of thumb, I always remember that if the hole cards are the same suit, there is around a 6% chance of making a flush by the river. If 3 players are all in, then you would be contributing 25% of the pot giving you 3-1 odds (assuming they all cover you and blinds and antes are insignificant). This was not a good call purely based on pot odds, but it is also useful to remember that if you do make a flush you can still be beat by a better hand.

Comment: Suited 10-J has other ways to win--high pairs and straights, for example. Indeed, it's better to flop the straight than the flush, because the straight will be the nuts. I would always call TJs with these odds, especially in good position.